# json.Net + handle deserialization error based on attribute on a property

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following class structure

```
public class Parent
{
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDeserializationErrors] // This attribute can be here
    public FirstLevel FirstLevelProperty { get; set; }
}

public class FirstLevel
{
    public int AnotherProperty { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDeserializationErrors] // Or this can be here
    public SecondLevel SecondLevelProperty { get; set; }
}

public class SecondLevel
{
    public int OneMoreProperty { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDeserializationErrors] //Or Here
    public string YetAnotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And this Attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class IgnoreDeserializationErrorsAttribute : Attribute
{

}
```

How can I tell Json.NET to ignore errors for all the properties which have the `IgnoreDeserializationErrorsAttribute` attribute.

I tried

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Parent>(someJson, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Error = (s, e) => { 
                bool attributeDefined = true;//TODO: How do I get the properties attributes here.

                if (attributeDefined)
                {
                    e.ErrorContext.Handled = true 
                }
            }
        });
```

but I am unable to populate the `attributeDefined` variable inside the delegate.

Is this possible inside the error handler? or do I have to create a custom converter.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in OnError attribute that can be used for this purpose. See below the sample from the official documentation:

```
public class PersonError
{
    private List<string> _roles;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public List<string> Roles
    {
        get
        {
            if (_roles == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Roles not loaded!");
            }

            return _roles;
        }
        set { _roles = value; }
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    [OnError]
    internal void OnError(StreamingContext context, ErrorContext errorContext)
    {
        errorContext.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Check [Serialization Error Handling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm) article for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Let's you have the following classes for the sake of simplicity:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }

    public FirstLevel FirstLevelProperty { get; set; }
}

public class FirstLevel
{
    public int AnotherProperty { get; set; }

    public SecondLevel SecondLevelProperty { get; set; }
}

public class SecondLevel
{
    public int OneMoreProperty { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDeserializationErrors]
    public int YetAnotherProperty { get; set; }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class IgnoreDeserializationErrorsAttribute : Attribute
{

}
```

> As you can notice I changed the type of `YetAnotherProperty` to `int` and only this property is decorated with `IgnoreDeserializationErrorsAttribute`

```
var someJson = "{\"SomeProperty\": 3, \"FirstLevelProperty\": {\"AnotherProperty\": 35, \"SecondLevelProperty\": {\"OneMoreProperty\": 359, \"YetAnotherProperty\": \"test\"}}}";

var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parent>(someJson, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Error = (s, e) =>
    {
        bool attributeDefined = false;

        if (e.CurrentObject == null) return;

        PropertyInfo property = e.CurrentObject.GetType().GetProperty(e.ErrorContext.Member.ToString());

        if (property == null) return;

        var attr = property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof (IgnoreDeserializationErrorsAttribute));

        if (attr != null) attributeDefined = true;

        if (attributeDefined) e.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
    }
});
```

The code in the error handler reads the property that caused the error, checks if the property is decorated with `IgnoreDeserializationErrorsAttribute` and sets the `Handled` property of the ErrorContext accordingly.

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zIj5RN

Comment: Thanks but this wont work if I put the attribute on "SecondLevelProperty" and want to ignore all deserailization errors for any member of the SecondLevel class.